# why does zed exit after resume?

Tags: 22.04, systemd, zfs

I use ZFS on my desktop. I want `zed(8)` (ZFS event daemon) running constantly so I'm logging stuff like scrubs, trims, and problems.

For some reason, zed exits after I resume my desktop from suspend. Here's a snippet from the systemd journal:

```
Dec 14 08:29:06 host kernel: PM: suspend exit
Dec 14 08:29:06 host systemd-resolved[22015]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Dec 14 08:29:06 host zed[22320]: Exiting
Dec 14 08:29:06 host systemd-sleep[54610]: System returned from sleep state.
Dec 14 08:29:06 host systemd[1]: zfs-zed.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Anyone know why zed exits after resume?

I grep'd around a bunch but I didn't find any code/config to purposely kill/deactivate zed after resume.

My workaround is to manually patch the service like so:

```
--- /tmp/zfs-zed.service    2023-12-14 10:45:58.730118213 -0800
+++ /lib/systemd/system/zfs-zed.service 2023-12-14 10:46:34.765996601 -0800
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@
 
 [Service]
 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zed -F
-Restart=on-abort
+Restart=always
 
 [Install]
 Alias=zed.service
```

Then run:

```bash
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable zfs-zed.service --now
```

Comment: I'd say this is a bug in the default service configuration. You should probably report it.

Answer (score 1):

The zed `restart` setting was changed from `on-abort` to `always` in OpenZFS 2.2.

https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/commit/bd9dc5a1dcc1d2ec88477af3f6f0bc8c9bdef286

I confirmed I have `zfs-zed` version `2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.2`, so I'll need to use the workaround for now.